# Google Ads API: Should the CLICK_VIEW resource contain APP campaign GCLIDs? It does not appear to have access to them

Tags: android, google-ads-api, attribution

While attempting to attribute Android installations to specific Google Ads campaigns, I noticed that a client app instance is loaded with a string called the [installReferrer](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer).
This string is (often times) automatically populated with the GCLID for the click that led to the Play Store Listing Page visit.

However, I tried cross referencing these GCLIDs with the Google Ads API CLICK_VIEW resource, and I can't find any matches. I even decided to pull all GCLIDs for an entire month from this resource, hundreds of thousands of records, and then I noticed not a single GCLID pertains to an [APP Campaign](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6247380?hl=en).

Is this by design, or am I perhaps doing something wrong?
Here's the query I use to try locating an individual GCLID:

```
SELECT                                                   
  customer.id,                                            
  segments.date,                                        
  ad_group.type,                                        
  click_view.gclid,                                       
  campaign.resource_name,                       
  campaign.advertising_channel_type,         
  ad_group.resource_name,                        
  click_view.ad_group_ad,                           
  metrics.clicks                                           
FROM click_view                                        
WHERE                                                      
  segments.date = RELEVANT_DATE_HERE                   
  AND click_view.gclid = GCLID_GOES_HERE
```